# How to deactivate venv while using fish?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fish, python-venv

I have installed venv using python3 with fish like and activated using env/bin/activate.fish, but there is no deactivate.fish in env/bin/

```
➜ ls env/bin/
activate         activate.fish    easy_install     pip              pip3.7           python3
activate.csh     chardetect       easy_install-3.7 pip3             python           yapf
```

how can I deactivate venv?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In opposite to `activate`, `deactivate` is implemented as a shell function, not as a shell script or binary in `env/bin`. You can verify that by running:

```
type -t deactivate 
function
```

To run the function and deactivate the virtualenv, just run `deactivate`

PS: This behaviour is the same for all shells, it is not special to `fish`.